# Random string generator from JavaScript for kids challenge

Tags: javascript, string, random, generator

I want to ask about the random string generator challenge. So, I got this quiz from JavaScript for kids book from no starch press publisher. I'm newbie and very confused about this challenge, can somebody help me?

====================

## Random string generator

"Make a random string generator. You’ll need to start with a 
string containing all the letters in the alphabet:
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
To pick a random letter from this string, you can 
update the code we used for the random insult generator in 
Chapter 3: Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length). This 
will create a random index into the string. You can then use 
square brackets to get the character at that index.
To create the random string, start with an empty string 
(var randomString = ""). Then, create a while loop that will 
continually add new random letters to this string, as long 
as the string length is less than 6 (or any length you choose). 
You could use the += operator to add a new letter to the end 
of the string. After the loop has finished, log it to the console 
to see your creation!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, these instructions are a bit inside out, here in the correct order:

```js
// You’ll need to start with a string containing all the letters in the alphabet: 

var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

//  To create the random string, start with an empty string

var randomString = "";

// Then, create a while loop that will continually add new random letters to this string, as long as the string length is less than 6 (or any length you choose). 

while (randomString.length < 6) {

  // To pick a random letter from this string, you can update the code we used for the random insult generator in Chapter 3

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
  
  // You can then use square brackets to get the character at that index. 

  var randomChar = alphabet[randomIndex];
  
  // You could use the += operator to add a new letter to the end of the string. 

  randomString += randomChar;
  
}
  
//  After the loop has finished, log it to the console to see your creation!

console.log(randomString);
```

Comment: Thanks georg, you really help me :)